# Laravel: can't upload information from form

Tags: php, database, laravel, upload

I am trying to create a form that a logged in user can upload product information to the DB. Then I want the user to be able to see the product information in a list(only the products he/she uploaded).

Here is the error I get when I hit submit button.

> 403 This action is unauthorized.

when I reload the page, this error shows up.

> BadMethodCallException
> Call to undefined method App\Models\User::products()
> http://localhost:8000/products

I think the problem is in the way how I'm trying to reach the product information. I have 2 tables which are users table and products table, and these 2 are related. What I tried to do is get the logged in user information by `Auth::user()` and get to the products table which has the user_id column.

This is my code in ProductController.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests\ProductRequest;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Auth::user()->products()->get();

        return view('product.show')->with(['products' => $products]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('product.create');
    }

    public function store(ProductRequest $request)
    {
        $product = new Product;
        $product->user_id = $request->user()->id;
        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/product');
            $product->image = basename($path);
        }
        $product->save();
        return redirect('/product/create')->with('message', 'registration success!');
    }
}
```

Maybe

```
$products = Auth::user()->products()->get();
```

is not the right way to do it? But what I'm confused with is that this is part is for showing the product information and why it's preventing me from uploading information.

Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Thank you in advance.

**additional information**
User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function tests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Test');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Comment: `user()->products()` would be a relationship created in your User model, so it depends on how that's set up.

Comment: `403 This action is unauthorized.` error because, you have to authorize the form request, either write your own authorization code or just `return true;` in `authorize()` method in your form validation class `ProductRequest`. Refer [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#authorizing-form-requests)

Comment: You might missed the `products()` relation in the `User` model.  That would be the reason for `BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Models\User::products()`. Please refer [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: Hi iamab.in,
I changed authorize() method to true and now the information is being uploaded!
However I still can't show the list of products. It seems like 403 and BadMethodCallException were 2 different problems...

Comment: @toyop Check my second comment, can you share the `User.php` model class?

Comment: I just added the User.php in the question. Thank you a lot for helping me out.

Comment: In your error `User` class's namespace is `App\Models\User` but the user class you shared here is under `App\User`. Do you have two user models?

Comment: Actually there's one User model I unintentionally created while ago. Do you think that's causing the problem? App\Model\User is the one that I don't need.

Comment: Sorry, App/User is the one that I don't need. Should I delete it?

Comment: That might be the reason for the error. You could delete the unwanted/additional User class. If you are deleting `App/User` then add the `products()` method  and other required methods in `App\Model\User`.

Comment: Hey,
I wrote the code in the right User.php and now it's working! Thank you so much for your help iamab.ing!  I wouldn't have figured this out on my own.
Could you add the solution in the answer section so that I can choose your answer?

Comment: Glad it helped.. I am away from my desk, so won't be able to add an answer right now. You could add the answer your own.✌️